# Why margin-top and margin-bottom are called "vertical margins"

Tags: css

Why `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` are called "vertical margins" despite the fact they're laying horizontally around the box ?

Spec says about margin collapsing : "**Note that vertical margins between the LI boxes collapse**." (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)

But I've looked several examples of margins collapsing, and all I see is horizontal lines and boxes...

EDIT : since the question was unclear, I did a drawing of what I'm calling "laying horizontally around the box" : 
[vertical margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qan14.gif)

Comment: The measurement is in the vertical plane

Comment: Exactly this question has been asked before.

Comment: connexo I looked it up before asking but I didn't finda similar question. Can you share the link ?

Comment: *they're laying horizontally around the box ?* I can't understand this question. They're laying vertically around the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line between the top and bottom is vertical. Since the margins to the top and bottom form a frame to the ends of this line, they are called vertical margins.

Or put differently: when you progress through your page from top to bottom (ie. in vertical direction), you start at the top margin and end at the bottom margin.